# angular loading a json file on a form

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

I've started recently working with angular and node.js. I'm trying to populate the content of a json file on some html forms depending on the option selected on a drop down list. I managed to do that but the problem is as soon as I change the content of the form manually, if I want to load the value that it was before (selecting the option from the drop down list) the value of the form doesn't change keeping the one I put manually.

Does anybody know if there's a way to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Sandra.

Here it's my code:

```
- json file: content that I want to populate on the forms
[
    {
        "host": "server1",
        "user": "dan",
        "pwd": "123456",
        "remotedir": "OUT",
        "localdir": "65_cargo/dmshared",
        "pattern":"FNVAC",
        "archive": "0",
        "monitor": "2"
    },
    {
        "host": "ftp.xmap.com",
        "user": "pront",
        "pwd": "x14ck",
        "remotedir": "OUT",
        "localdir": "107_sss/dmshared",
        "pattern":"csv",
        "archive": "0",
        "monitor": "2"
    }
]

-html file: website

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="gtApp">
  <head>
    <!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script-->
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="ftpsites.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ftpSitesCtrl">
    <h1>TTS GetTrack Control Panel</h1>
    <h2>Total FTP Sites {{ getTotalSites() }}</h2> 
    <p>Select Site</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.host for item in ftpsites">
    </select>
    <div>
      <p>Edit Site Details</p>
      <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Host</td>
          <td><input type="text" value="{{selectedItem.host}}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="{{selectedItem.user}}"/></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="{{selectedItem.pwd}}"/></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Remote Directory</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="{{selectedItem.remotedir}}"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Local Directory</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="{{selectedItem.localdir}}"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>File Pattern</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="{{selectedItem.pattern}}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Archive</td>
            <td><select><option selected>No</option><option>Yes</option></selected></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monitor (Days)</td>
            <td><select><option="{{selectedItem.monitor}}"></option></selected></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

js file: logic

var gtApp  =  angular.module('gtApp', []);

gtApp.controller('ftpSitesCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('ftpsites.json').success(function (data){
        $scope.ftpsites = data;
    });

    $scope.getTotalSites = function(){
        return $scope.ftpsites.length;    
    } 

    $scope.populateData = function(){
        $scope.host=ftpsites.host;
        //return $scope;

    }
});
```

Comment: please add the code for ftpSitesCtrl

Answer (score 1):

On each of the inputs change "value" to "ng-model" (no curly brackets)

> value - one time bind, prints the value to the placeholder
>
> ng-model - two way binding to the model object

### Sample

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="formSelectedItem.pattern"/></td>
```

EDIT:

try add this code on your controller:

```
$scope.formSelectedItem = {};
$scope.$watch('selectedItem', function(newVal) {
    $scope.formSelectedItem = newVal;
});
```

Notice the change in the ng-model attribute

Comment: Thanks Ben, but if I do that then the options of my drop down list change when I insert a new value on the form. Is there a way to keep my list of options and edit the form value at the same time? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It wouldnt affect the list because you use the selectedItem variable which if I understand is not part of the list @user2746984

Comment: You said it wouldn't affect the list but it does. I've just made the changes you told me and as soon as I enter a new host the drop down list has changed

Comment: @user2746984 notice the change

Comment: Thanks Ben, but it does the same. So when I typing the new value of the form the drop down option automatically changed as well.